# How do I update the content of a table cell from another knockoutJS binding context using a different textarea as source?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am attempting to edit or update the `ArtistBio` which is bind using a `Knockout foreach loop`. However, I need to do this using a `textarea` and then hit submit to perform the update.

Here is a [JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dvnwmkLp/1/):

What's confusing is, the data is bind using a `foreach loop` and so there are no `Artist Bio observable`. And also, how do I make this update if the text area is in a different context, meaning that the source of the update is not in the View Model performing the initial binding?

How do I make this update the Artist Bio so that the table cell containing the text is updated?

I attempted to do it this way using `JQuery` and writing directly to the `Observable Array`:

*Update HTML code:*

Update Bio

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Artist ID</th>
        <th>Musical Bio</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ArtistBio">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: ArtistId"></td>
        <td>
            <textarea readonly="readonly" data-bind="value: Bio"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*Updated JS Code:*

```
function ViewModelA() {

        var self = this;

        self.SelectedArtist = ko.observable();

        var artistList = [{
            "ArtistId": "1",
            "LastName": "Secada",
            "FirstName": "Jon"
        },

            {
                "ArtistId": "2",
                "LastName": "Dion",
                "FirstName": "Celine"

            }
        ];


        self.Artists = ko.computed(function() {
            return ko.utils.arrayMap(artistList,

                    function(artist) {

                        return {

                            FullName: artist.FirstName + ' ' + artist.LastName,
                            value: artist.ArtistId
                        }
                    });
        });
    }

    function ViewModelB(vma) {

        var self = this;

        self.artistDetail = ko.observableArray([{
            "ArtistId": "1",
            "Bio": "Jon Secada is a Cuban American singer and songwriter. " +
            "Secada was born in Havana, Cuba, and raised in Hialeah, Florida. " +
            "He has won two Grammy Awards and sold 20 million albums since his " +
            "English-language debut album in 1992"
        },

            {
                "ArtistId": "2",
                "Bio": "Céline Marie Claudette Dion, CC OQ ChLD is a Canadian " +
                "singer, songwriter, businesswoman and occasional actress."
            }
        ]);




        self.ArtistBio = ko.computed(function() {
            if (vma.SelectedArtist()) {
                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.artistDetail(), function(item) {

                    // Access the selected value here and return matching actist
                    return item.ArtistId === vma.SelectedArtist().value;
                });
            }
        });

    }

    var viewModelA = new ViewModelA();
    var viewModelB = new ViewModelB(viewModelA);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModelA, document.getElementById('artist-list'));
    ko.applyBindings(viewModelB, document.getElementById('artist-detail'));

$(function(){
    $('#update').click(function(event) {
        var updateText = $('#update-bio').val();

        if(viewModelA.SelectedArtist()) {

        viewModelB.artistDetail()[viewModelA.SelectedArtist().value -1].Bio = updateText;
        }
    });
});
```

Using the above I am able to directly modify the array value: However, I have to re-select the Artist to see the change. How do I immediately show the change on submit?

I am not sure how else to do it.

Comment: It is a li confuse, you want to change the ````ViewModelA```` that was binding to  ````artist-list````, or you want to get the context of the ````ArtistBio````?

Comment: Hey Joel: I am trying to update the `Artist Bio` text in the `textarea` binding. For example: I need to add an additional textarea which I can use to enter some text and update the Artist bio on submit, not the entire `obseravableArray`, just the `Artist Bio`.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `textarea` to not be `readonly` and use a `value` binding instead of `text`, you can edit it where it is.

```
<textarea data-bind="value: Bio"></textarea>
```

Your fiddle doesn't include any separate area for editing the information, so it's not clear how you want that to work. Your example code has a jQuery event bound to an id that isn't in your updated HTML, but you shouldn't be using jQuery DOM selectors in your viewmodel anyway.

I recommend against having separate viewmodels for different sections of the view. Just have one viewmodel that includes all the pieces. If you want to have modular components, use [Knockout components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html).